# How to display multiple value from query result in input fields?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a query result.

```
    | id | name     |
    -----------------
    | 3  | candi    |
    | 4  | gedangan |
    | 11 | sidoarjo |
```

My problem is how to display my query result into a single input field.

```
<input type="text" name="tags" id="" value="Candi, Gedangan, Sidoarjo" />
```

This is my query.

```
<?php 
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT kecamatan.KECAMATAN_ID , kecamatan.KECAMATAN_NAMA
         FROM sumber_air a 
         JOIN sumber_air_kecamatan ON a.ID_SUMBER=sumber_air_kecamatan.ID_SUMBER
         JOIN kecamatan ON sumber_air_kecamatan.KECAMATAN_ID=kecamatan.KECAMATAN_ID
         WHERE a.ID_SUMBER = " . $_GET['id'] . "'
         GROUP BY kecamatan.KECAMATAN_ID");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     <input type=text name=tags value=<?=$row['KECAMATAN_NAMA'];?> />
}
?>
```

Comment: fyi, mysql functions are deprecated, use mysqli or pdo

Comment: Why are you injecting HTML (form input) into your `while` loop? You also need to quote `type=text name=tags`

Comment: ...including the value, while removing the short tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : you're right, my mistake.

Comment: Check out the answers below. Hopefully they've fixed the issue. @and_riyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<?php 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT kecamatan.KECAMATAN_ID , kecamatan.KECAMATAN_NAMA
       FROM sumber_air a 
       JOIN sumber_air_kecamatan ON a.ID_SUMBER=sumber_air_kecamatan.ID_SUMBER
       JOIN kecamatan ON sumber_air_kecamatan.KECAMATAN_ID=kecamatan.KECAMATAN_ID
       WHERE a.ID_SUMBER = " . $_GET['id'] . "'
       GROUP BY kecamatan.KECAMATAN_ID");

    $tags = '';

    //adds every "KECAMATAN_NAMA" to $tags, seperated by ", "
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $tags .= $row['KECAMATAN_NAMA'] . ', ';
    }

    //rtim($tags, ', ') removes the last ", " from the tags
    echo '<input type="text" name="tags" value="' . rtrim($tags, ', ') . '"/>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$value = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $value .= $row['KECAMATAN_NAMA'].", ";
}

echo '<input type="text" name="tags" value="'.$value.'" />';
```

Comment: You're doing the same error OP is doing, injecting HTML into PHP `<input type=text name=tags value=<?=$value;?> />`

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    // Build up a string of results
    $res .= $row['KECAMATAN_NAMA']. ", ";
}

//Remove last comma
$res = rtrim($res, ', ');

//Echo result
echo '<input type="text" name="tags" value="'.$res.'" />';
```

Comment: This will generate a parse error. Check your quotes on the type and name.

Comment: That's not my DV btw. Edit: Seems like the person retracted it.

Comment: Why the `' />'` in front of every comma?

Comment: @Jonan Forgot to remove that! Updated

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha, haters gonna hate!

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all the values into an array, and then join them with `implode`

```
$names_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $names_array[] = htmlentities($row['KECAMATAN_NAMA']);
}
$names = implode(', ', $names_array);
echo "<input type='text' name='tags' value='$names'/>";
```

Comment: 'You need to collect all the values into an array' there are other possiblities. You make it sound like its the only way.